# Bootstrap 4 alert box close button not aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap and I currently have an alert box:

```
<div class="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible" id="delAlbumAlert">
  <span><strong>Delete Album!</strong> Select the album(s) you want to delete.</span>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="return handleOptions($('#btnDeleteAlbum'));">
    <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:black;">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

The close button is not aligned vertically. Here is how it shows up.

[image: img]

How can I make the button aligned? I tried using the `<div clas="alert..." style="top: -4px;">` and it kind of worked but I was wondering if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `padding-top` property of the button like the following:

```css
.close {
    padding-top: .60rem !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible" id="delAlbumAlert">
  <span><strong>Delete Album!</strong> Select the album(s) you want to delete.</span>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="return handleOptions($('#btnDeleteAlbum'));">
    <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:black;">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the class `alert-dismissable` because it's not necessary to make the alert dismissable, this class only has styling purposes. You can use flexbox to align the close-button vertically:

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade show d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <i class="fa-duotone fa-circle-exclamation fa-lg me-auto"></i>
    <span class="me-auto px-3">This is a success alert ...</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
</div>
```

Important is to use `data-bs-dismiss="alert"` attribute.

[image]